# Knitting .Rmd in VSCode stuck at 0%

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, r-markdown, pandoc

I've been using RStudio for a while, but want to switch to vsc. I have followed the instructions for the R-extension. VSC recognizes the chunks in the rmd-file, but it wont allow me to knit to html. The loading is stuck a 0%. Any tips og tricks?

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ag21w.png)]

I have changed the Files: Associations to

```
{
   "files.associations": {
     "*.Rmd": "rmd"
  }
}
```

and have ensured pandoc is installed.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's too little information for anyone to give some useful advice. Try opening the terminal tab (ctrl+') and navigate to the output subtab, and select "R markdown" in the dropdown menu. Hopefully, there will be more information there.

Comment: It seems likely that something in your code is causing a hang. Do you have any `browser()`, anything prompting the user to enter something, or similar? Your question needs more information, there's nothing we can know about what's going on in your document without seeing it.

Comment: In my case, when I press the knit button I have the same problem, it shows 0% and in the output it says `[VSC-R] test.Rmd process started
==> rmarkdown::render('d:\\path\\test.Rmd')` When I manually run `rmarkdown::render("test.Rmd")` in the terminal it does the knitting.